# err is prompting while compiling class which imports dk.nashorn.internal.objects.annotations in java 11

Tags: java

error: package sun.nio.ch is not visible
import sun.nio.ch.IOUtil;
              ^
  (package sun.nio.ch is declared in module java.base, which does not export it to the unnamed module)

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: You should not be using classes from the package `sun.nio.ch`. These classes are internal and are not accessible anymore when you use JDK 11. Use only the publicly documented classes in the Java API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All packages until `jdk.*` are private to the JVM and shouldn't be accessed directly.  You can enable the compiler and JVM to let you use them, but you should explore all other possible options first.

Comment: can it work when we include  require jdk.nashorn.scripting in module-info?

Comment: @DikshaSingh096 that wouldn't be avoiding using it however. ;)